# EXC_BAD_ACCESS on nil checking optional in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, uiimageview, exc-bad-access

**EDIT 2: After changing some completely unrelated code the crash happens again. Even if I try to revert the code changes, it crashes again.**

**EDIT: After updating to iOS 9.2 (from 9.1) it works without any problem again.**

The following code gives me an EXC_BAD_ACCESS on the nil check:

```
if(self.imageViews != nil){
    for (_,element) in self.imageViews!.enumerate(){
        element.removeFromSuperview()
    }
}
```

The property is defined as follows:

```
class ImageAdditionalContent : AdditionalContentView {
    var imageViews : [UIImageView]?
```

Even if I try to first assign an empty array to it, it gives me an EXC_BAD_ACCESS on the assignment:

```
self.imageViews = []
```

Even more interesting is, that it worked perfectly a day ago. If I remove the whole code, run the app, quit it, add the code again and run it again, it crashes on the for loop for the first time and afterwards again on the nil check.

Answer (score 1):

I would take advantage of optionals here. As to your EXC_BAD_ACCESS I would check not just the status of the UIImageView array but self. Set a breakpoint before the assignment and see what's going on. If this worked fine a day ago I would also look at what code changes have happen in your project.

```
    if let elements = self.imageViews {
        for element in elements {
            element.removeFromSuperview()
        }
    } else {
        print("self.imageViews is nil! \(self.imageViews)") 
    }
```

Comment: @DJ_Lectr0 Does it still crash at element.removeFromSuperview()?

Comment: Here is where it is crashing? : if(self.imageViews != nil)

Comment: Yes exactly. Even with your swift approach above.

Comment: Ok, so let me try to understand. You have replaced the code you have completely with the code I posted and it now crashes at 'let elements = self.imageViews'? Enter this line above it and let me know if it still crashes in the same place 'print("self: \(self)")

Comment: Exactly. But it worked a few days ago after upgrading my test phone to 9.2. Now it does not work anymore. With your code or mine.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/98409/discussion-between-fragilecat-and-dj-lectr0).